# Anagram Checking Logical Error - Cant seem to find the error

Tags: java, anagram

```
public class AnagramUnoptimized {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String a  = "good";
    String b  = "ogod";
    boolean isAnagram = false;

    String c = a.toLowerCase();
    String d = b.toLowerCase();

    if(c.length()==d.length()) {
        boolean [] Visited = new boolean[a.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < c.length(); i++) {
            isAnagram = false;
            for (int j = 0; j < d.length(); j++) {
                if (c.charAt(i) == d.charAt(j) && Visited[j]==false) {
                    isAnagram = true;
                    Visited[j] = true;
                }
            }
            if (isAnagram == false) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if(isAnagram==true){
        System.out.println("The given Strings are Anagrams");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("The given Strings are not Anagrams");
    }

  }
}
```

I used a Visited boolean array to check for repeated items but its now showing "Not anagram" for all inputs....

Can you tell me why its showing "Not anagram" if the strings have repeating elements??

Comment: Try sorting the letters in each string and comparing the result. Also, as a matter of style, your local variable `Visited` should begin with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Using a debugger would be very useful in cases like that. I highly encourage you to do so before checking the answers here, just for practice. Come back later to see if you got it right by yourself. For start, you can add breakpoints in the lines where you update the value of `isAnagram`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is you are continuing with the loop even when `visited[j]` is changed to `true` whereas you need to break the inner loop at this point. Do it as follows:

```
for (int j = 0; j < d.length(); j++) {
    if (c.charAt(i) == d.charAt(j) && visited[j] == false) {
        isAnagram = true;
        visited[j] = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

**The output after this change:**

```
The given Strings are Anagrams
```

A better way to do it would be as follows:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = "good";
        String b = "ogod";

        char[] first = a.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
        char[] second = b.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(first);
        Arrays.sort(second);

        boolean isAnagram = Arrays.equals(first, second);

        if (isAnagram == true) {
            System.out.println("The given Strings are Anagrams");
        } else {
            System.out.println("The given Strings are not Anagrams");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
The given Strings are Anagrams
```

Comment: Good answer, but the question is actually about what is the error in the original code. Including that info would make this answer even more helpful I think

Comment: Thanks, @vefthym for the encouraging words. I am looking into his answer currently to find the problem. I'll update my answer to put my finding.

Comment: I've found the problem with OP's code and also updated my answer to incorporate it.

Comment: Thanks Guys, That (break;) did the trick.... really appreciate your help and support...

Answer (score 0):

In your code you should break the inner for loop when the
condition "if  (c.charAt(i) == d.charAt(j) && Visited[j]==false)"
has been meet. Because it is still looping through the second stiring and if it will meet the same char one angain it will change the value of Visited[] to true two times, leading to an error. It this example this is the case witch char 'o'. Adding  " break; " at the end of the if statement should fix the problem.